# Suggestions for learning new techniques during postdoc training

Tags: research-process, postdocs, job-search, biology, learning

I am about to finish my PhD. My PhD work mainly have computational biology focus(60%) and rest of them are experimental biology. Due to lack of experimental biology  goal I am thinking of learning new techniques during my postdoc training. Although I performed the experimental work smoothly during my PhD training. Is it possible to learn new techniques and experiment during postdoctoral training? or the postdoc PI normally expects that the PhD graduate should know every experimental detail?

Comment: I expect my staff to keep learning new things through their entire career.